# Можно ли спавнить разные объекты через Instantiate?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два префаба, можно ли сделать так, чтобы они создавались с помощью одной функции?

Comment: То есть - через один вызов `Instantinate`?

Comment: Да, за один вызов

Comment: Тогда нет ([см. документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)). Лучше просто вызовите функцию два раза.

Answer (score 3):

#### Нет, нельзя.

Собственно вот все перегрузки функции `Instantiate`:

- ```cs
  public static Object Instantiate(Object original);
  ```
- ```cs
  public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
  ```
- ```cs
  public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent, bool instantiateInWorldSpace);
  ```
- ```cs
  public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
  ```
- ```cs
  public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
  ```

Как видите тут все перегрузки принимают и возвращают одно значение. Соответственно просто так это не делать.

---

#### Тогда какие варианты есть?

Можете сделать собственную перегрузку `Instantiate`, поскольку уже в Unity 2019.-.- можно изменить заводские скрипты. Но этот вариант имеет свои минусы: при обновлении Unity с огромной вероятностью восстановится изначальный скрипт (то есть ваша перегрузка исчезнет).

---

#### Самый надёжный способ

Почему не использовать эту функцию дважды? Или же если объектов много, почему не использовать цикличное создание:

```cs
[SerializedField] private GameObject[] _JustAnObjectsArray;

private void Start()
{
    foreach(GameObject _Object in _JustAnObjectsArray)
    {
        Instantiate(_Object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятна цель: почему так важно создавать два объекта в одной функции? Вообще, функция [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) имеет всего 5 перегрузок (подробнее почитайте по ссылке):

1. Создание объекта
2. Создание объекта с родителем
3. Создание объекта с родителем и булевским параметром instantiateInWorldSpace
4. Создание компонента в указанной позиции и с указанным вращением
5. Создание объекта с родителем в указанной позиции и с указанным вращением.

Как видите, ни одна из перегрузок метода Instantiate() не принимает двух параметров типа GameObject, что говорит о том, что вы не можете создать одной командой сразу 2 объекта. Поэтому все, что я могу вам предложить это вызвать функцию Instantiate дважды одна за одной. Это лучший вариант и ничего проще нет

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать свой метод, принимающий список объектов. В цикле метода инстанциируем все объекты из списка

Comment: Слушайте, наверху два замечательных ответа. Зачем писать писать еще что-то непонятное из двух предложений? Я не против, конечно, но отвечайте лучше на новые вопросы и отвечайте нормально, распространенно. Рекомендовать удаление я не буду, но на будущее учтите.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]